# Lua C API - attaching data to a coroutine

Tags: c, api, lua, coroutine

Is there a way to attach data to a coroutine, or at least to somehow identify different coroutines?

I am trying to implement a timer API where the timers are controlled by the host, that looks something like the following on the Lua side:

```lua
function callback()
  local timer = ElapsedTimer()
  ...
end

function main()
  local timer = CreateTimer(...)

  StartTimer(timer, callback, ...)
end
```

The `StartTimer()` call sends the timer and callback to the C side, and the C side will eventually call the callback in a new coroutine.

The call to `ElapsedTimer()` needs to return data that is specific to this coroutine/thread, i.e. in this case the timer.

In pseudo code:

```c
int StartTimer(lua_State* L) {
    auto timer = ...;
    auto coroutine = ???

    coroutine.userdata = &timer; // But probably store an actual structure with more pointers

    return 0;
}

int ElapsedTimer(lua_State* L) {
    auto coroutine = ???
    auto timer = (Timer*)coroutine.userdata;

    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, timer)

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just now realized I need to use `lua_newthread` to create the coroutine, which means I have a separate `lua_State` object.
This means I can always create a mapping between the coroutine's state and whatever data I want in the host language (e.g. in a map data structure)

Answer (score 0):

This is what userdata is for:

```
int StartTimer(lua_State* L) {

    TimerStruct timer = (TimerStruct*)lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(TimerStruct));
    //allocates some memory and returns pointer to it
    timer->//...

    // lua_setuservalue will let you bind the callback to the timer

    return 1; //actually return it
}
```

Also it is going to be easier to pass the timer along

```
function callback(timer)
  ...
end
```

That way the lua code doesn't need to query that value. It already got it.

Comment: I realize passing arguments is easier, however I am implementing an API not designed by me. Either way, I have many more of these getters that are coroutine-specific, and I would really want to figure a general implementation. It's almost like using a closure, but the environment of the closure isn't directly accessible to the Lua side.

Comment: To elaborate, the API is event-based, and every time an event triggers actions to run, a new coroutine is used, and the event data needs to be attached to the coroutine in some way or another (but indeed, accessible in that weird way, rather than arguments).